# rails to_json return single field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-5.1.6

I'm using the method ".to_json" to render my result like this:

"this is a route in my controller"

```
def show_articles
      render json: @company_repo.get_articles_by_company_id(params[:id])
                       .to_json(include: [{product_groups: {except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}},
                                          {ean13: {only: :code}},
                                          {article_designations: {only: :designation}}])
end
```

I'm using this method to ask my DB:

"This is in my repository"

```
  def get_articles_by_company_id(id)
    Article.all
        .joins(product_groups: [{laboratory: :company}])
        .joins(:ean13)
        .joins(:article_designations)
        .where('companies.id = ?', id)
        .where('article_designations.locale_id = 1')
  end
```

My problem is: I want to get the "designation" from "article_designations" table with the "locale_id" 1. I have each time just one designation with the id 1.

So now I get this in my result:

```
"article_designations": [
    {
        "designation": "Procedente igitur mox tempore cum adventicium"
    }
]
```

But finaly I want this :

```
"designation": "Procedente igitur mox tempore cum adventicium"
```

How can I proceed to have just the key/value and not key/value(array) => key/value?

Thanks

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using "Rails 5.1.6"

Comment: You can try .as_json(root: false) as per this doc - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html
can you try that let me know if it works

Comment: also here, I notice this is what added the root label - `{article_designations: {only: :designation}}` after removing the root i.e `root: false`, you are going to want to change `article_designations: {only: :designation}` to `designation: {only: :designation}`

Comment: What do you mean with ".as_json(root: false)"? chain this after my ".to_json(include: ......" ) ? Like this : .to_json(include: ...... ).as_json(root: false)?

Comment: I tried like this: 
      render json: @company_repo.get_articles_by_company_id(params[:id])
                       .as_json(root: false, include: [{product_groups: {except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}},
                                          {ean13: {only: :code}},
                                          designation: {only: :designation}])

but no results

Comment: do you know this gem? - https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: that gem gives u full control of how u want your models to look like, hence you will save yourself from using too much `include`, `only` and `exclude` - https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md#root
You can see the use of root in that link.

Comment: find full documentation here, I hope you will find it useful - https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/README.md

Comment: No I don't know it! thanks for the link, I would like to read the doc. Do you know https://github.com/rails/jbuilder ?
probably I can work on the structure of the json but I don't know if it's a good idea. What do you think?

Comment: Better to use ActiveModelSerializer. I've used it on multiple projects. Never really used jbuilder so I don't know. But from what I see, it looks like with jbuilder you get to write more code.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your responses! I would check your solution "active_model_serializers". Thanks